# Does WIC support AVIF files?

Tags: windows, winapi, wic, avif

My understanding is that Windows has an AVIF codec. I would like to read AVIF files using WIC, but don't see GUID_ContainerFormatAVIF (or anything similar) defined anywhere. Without this information I can't add AVIF support to my program. Anyone know if there is a WIC AVIF codec or what the GUID for it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WIC HEIF HEIC image decoding C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294983/wic-heif-heic-image-decoding-c)

Comment: Thanks. It might help if I were trying to read HEIC files, which I already support. Without a codec and the magic GUID however I can't read AVIF files using WIC.

Comment: Actually this might be a clue to the solution in that the HEIC codec looks like it also supports AVIF. Need to try some more test images, but it seems to work.